# How to run coffeescript on page change?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm working on a Rails 4 app without turbolinks.

I know I can tell my coffee script to run with:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link').click (event) ->
    # some code
```

The problem is when I update the DOM with a new `toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link` it doesn't have the event attached to it.

How do I tell coffeescript to setup the event listeners on "page change" instead?

I've tried:

```
$(document).change ->
  $('.toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link').click (event) ->
    # some code
```

and

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(document).change ->
    $('.toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link').click (event) ->
      # some code
```

But both aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on` to bind to dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).ready ->

  $(document).on 'click', '.toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link', ->
```

Comment: How is `$(document).on 'click', '.toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link',` about to bind to `toggle_stage_item_edit_row_link`s even before they exist?

Comment: `on` binds to all existing and future elements. Check out http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/live/